# Error on C++ Scanner compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

i have error on RW when use number like (float,int,loop,right and left)
- right and left it means bracket

if last word of input is RW type  -> out put write twice RW 
 our input is  ->

```
Sahih Var01 := 122 |

%* Fgfghfghghghgjhgjgj
fgfghghfg       fh
ghghgfhghg *%
Sahih Var02 := 47 |
%% vgfghghjuyu5g5g55g5g5h5jh5j5hj5h55hu5h5j
Ashar Var03 := 121.75 |
Sahih Var04 := Var01 + Var02 |
Agar Var03 <> 100.0 
    LeftB 
        Var03 := Var03 ^ 2 |

    RightB
Halgheh ( Var01 : 1000 )
    LeftB
        Var02 :=    Var02      + 1 |
    RightB
Sahih
```

and out put after run is

```
( RW , SAHIH )ERROR( ID , 0 )( DL-OP , SET )( NUM , 122 )( DL-OP , EL )
COMMENT
( RW , SAHIH )( ID , 1 )( DL-OP , SET )( NUM , 47 )( DL-OP , EL )
COMMENT LINE
( RW , ASHAR )( ID , 2 )( DL-OP , SET )( NUM , 121.75 )( DL-OP , EL )
( RW , SAHIH )( ID , 3 )( DL-OP , SET )( ID , 0 )( DL-OP , ADD )( ID , 1 )( DL-OP , EL )
( RW , AGAR )( ID , 2 )( DL-OP , L&G )( RW , LEFT_B )( ID , 2 )( DL-OP , SET )( ID , 2 )( DL-OP , PWR )( NUM , 2 )( DL-OP , EL )
( RW , RIGHT_B )
( RW , HALGHEH )( DL-OP , OP )( ID , 0 )( DL-OP , CLN )( NUM , 1000 )( DL-OP , CP )( RW , LEFT_B )( ID , 1 )( DL-OP , SET )( ID , 1 )( DL-OP , ADD )( NUM , 1 )( DL-OP , EL )
( RW , RIGHT_B )
**( RW , SAHIH )( RW , SAHIH )** <<-- Error twice write output



   #define MAX 50
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct table{
    string type;
    string name;
}ST[MAX],RW[6],DL[17];
int main (){
    RW[0].type="Sahih";
    RW[0].name="SAHIH";
    RW[1].type="Ashar";
    RW[1].name="ASHAR";
    RW[2].type="Agar";
    RW[2].name="AGAR";
    RW[3].type="Halgheh";
    RW[3].name="HALGHEH";
    RW[4].type="LeftB";
    RW[4].name="LEFT_B";
    RW[5].type="RightB";
    RW[5].name="RIGHT_B";
    DL[0].type="=";
    DL[0].name="EQUAL";
    DL[1].type="+";
    DL[1].name="ADD";
    DL[2].type="-";
    DL[2].name="SUB";
    DL[3].type="/";
    DL[3].name="DIV";
    DL[4].type="*";
    DL[4].name="MUL";
    DL[5].type="^";
    DL[5].name="PWR";
    DL[6].type="%";
    DL[6].name="RMD";
    DL[7].type=":=";
    DL[7].name="SET";
    DL[8].type=":";
    DL[8].name="CLN";
    DL[9].type="<>";
    DL[9].name="L&G";
    DL[10].type="<=";
    DL[10].name="LES";
    DL[11].type=">=";
    DL[11].name="GES";
    DL[12].type="<";
    DL[12].name="GS";
    DL[13].type=">";
    DL[13].name="LS";
    DL[14].type="|";
    DL[14].name="EL";
    DL[15].type=")";
    DL[15].name="CP";
    DL[16].type="(";
    DL[16].name="OP";
    fstream in("input.txt",ios::in);
    if(!in){
        cout<<"Input file can not open!"<<"\n;
        return 0;
    }
    fstream out ("output.txt",ios::out);
    if(!out){
        cout<<"Output file can not open!"<<"\n";
        return 0;
    }
    string str;
    int i=0,b=0,c=0;
    bool f=false;
    cout<<"Please wait...";
top:
    while(!in.eof()){
        cout<<".";
        in>>str;
        f=false;
        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
            if(str==RW[i].type){
                out<<"( "<<"RW "<<", "<<RW[i].name<<" )";
                        if(str==RW[5].type)out<<"\n";
                        goto top;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<17;i++){
            if(str==DL[i].type){
            out<<"( "<<"DL-OP "<<", "<<DL[i].name<<" )";
                        if(str==DL[14].type)out<<"\n";
                        goto top;
            }
        }
        if(str.compare(0,3,"Var")==0){
            if(isdigit(str[3])){
                if(isdigit(str[4])){
                    if(str.size()==5){
                        for(i=0;i<c;i++){
                            if(str==ST[i].type){
                                out<<"( "<<"ID "<<", "<<i<<" )";
                                goto top;
                            }
                    }
                                ST[c].type=str;
                                ST[c].name=c;
                                out<<"( "<<"ID "<<", "<<c<<" )";
                            c++; 
                                        goto top;

                    }
                     }
            }
        }
        i=0;
        b=0;
        while(i<str.size()){
        if(isdigit(str[i])){
            b++;
        }
        if(f==false){
            if(str[i]=='.'){
             b++;
                         f=true;
            }
        }
            i++;
        }
            if(b==i){
        out<<"( "<<"NUM "<<", "<<str<<" )";
                goto top;
        }
        if(str=="%%"){
        do{
            in>>str;
        }while(str=="\n");
        out<<"COMMENT LINE"<<"\n";
                goto top;
         }
             if(str=="%*"){
                do{
             in>>str;
        }while(str=="*%");
        out<<"COMMENT"<<"\n";
                goto top;
         }
         out<<"Error";
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<"Please open the output file to see the result!";
}
```

Comment: Your main()-statement is missing a return value (first error I can see)

Comment: @arc_lupus return on `main` is optional. Not sure why. Could be legacy.

Comment: `while(!in.eof())` is a logic error. All of the `goto` and a some code duplication can be eliminated with a few functions.